# How to handle post variable data while clicking on back buton

Tags: php, postback

I am trying to make some naviations like page 1 having some data which need to post on page 2. with the help of form & hidden elements i am sending that data to page 2 & accepting that using $_POST method.again having some data which need to send page 3 using same post method method & hidden input element. On page page 4 i am accepting data using same method like $_POST.I getting data over there as i want.

But I am trying to click back button from page 4 to page 3 then the page which having some data posted from page 2. that data is missing from there and getting error like "Confirm Form Resubmission". I have tried the same thing with $_SESSION but its not working here.

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue.[Kindly see this image attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WM7kC.png)

Comment: why don't you use `$_GET`? any special requirements?

Comment: $_GET is showing data in URL and its out of requirement.Can you Please suggest something to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use session mechanism to store intermediate data on server side between steps. To avoid form resubmit issue, redirect after each POST to the next step using header() function. So, each page will be loaded using GET method and easily be "Back" button compatible.

Comment: Yes I have used this one but getting same issue while coming back on previous page.

if(!empty($_POST['pid'])){
     $_SESSION['pid']=$_POST['pid'];
}
$pid=$_SESSION['pid'];

Comment: Improved my answer with info on how to avoid form resubmit issue

Answer (score 0):

That isn't an error page you're seeing.  The Confirm Form Resubmission page is asking if you want to post the data again.  So it is asking you if you want to reload Page 3, with the data sent from Page 2.

This is standard web browser practice, and is replicated across all browsers.

Possibly a stupid question, but have you actually tried reloading this page, and accepting the resubmission of data?

Comment: Yes I know that once you refresh the page you will get data as we want but problem is that we need to refresh page and normal user don't know about these things.I have raised the questions on the half of normal web user not developer point of view.

Comment: is there any other way to handle this issue without showing that resubmission issue ..??

Comment: Not simply.  The best way to do it would be to have the pages submit through a standard GET process.  Then the variables travel in the URL, and you don't get the POST resubmission issue.